# Using CSS, how can I get the pseudo-class 'empty' on Element B to affect the styling of Element A?

Tags: css

I have two very simple text fields, and I want to style the first element based on the 'empty' pseudo-class of the second.  How might I go about doing this?

```
<style type='text/css'>
#element-b:empty [MAKE ELEMENT-A BOLD]{

}
</style>   

<div id="element-a">Some Element</div>
<div id="element-b">Some Other Element</div>
```

Comment: Isn't this what you need? http://jsbin.com/AKEkejit/1/edit The accepted answer doesn't seem to do what you asked for..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the adjacent sibling selector `+`

```css
#element-a:empty + #element-b {font-weight:bold;}
```

The `+` selector will select the element that is placed right after the selected element.

**Update after question was updated**: It is impossible to select the previous element. With CSS, you can only select the next element, via the `+` sibling selector, but selecting the previous one is impossible.

Comment: Nice...but in the example, 'A' is before 'B'.  So I want to select the previous adjacent sibling...gonna tinker with what you provided and see.

Comment: @BlackjacketMack that is not what you originally asked in your question. To answer the newly updated question, that's impossible. You can't select the previous element, only the next.

Comment: @BlackjacketMack You can't tranverse the DOM tree, so that's not currently possible.

Comment: Hmmm...I never edited or updated the question.  The original question asked "I want to style the first element based on the 'empty' pseudo-class of the second".  But your help is appreciated.

Comment: Also 1+ .. I was going to post the same answer too. The question was changed, so this addressed it correctly.

Comment: The title seems to be `if a empty then b bold`. The code sample seems to mean the inverse `if b empty then a bold`.

Comment: @threeFourOneSixOneThree that's because the question's contents were later edited. Josh and me both wanted to answer the same thing, and I even double-checked if this was indeed the order of selecting he wanted to do before submitting my answer.

Comment: @Joeytje50 as far as I know we would see an indication that the question was edited. I have not seen it yet ( meaning 4 minutes previous).

Comment: I edited the title to be consistent with the question.  'A' and 'B' in the title should have been consistent with the description.  I'll mark this as the answer as soon as it will let me (2 min. remaining).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in CSS if you reverse the position of the elements in the code, like so:

```
<style type='text/css'>
#element-b:empty + #element-a {

}
</style>   

<div id="element-b">Some Other Element</div>
<div id="element-a">Some Element</div>
```

Now obviously your elements are out of position, but you can rearrange them fairly simply with some CSS positioning.

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Mmb88/2/). Delete the text from the element B to see element A bolded.